# How can I tell QWidget to show in the same place that it was before it was hidden?

Tags: qt

If I create and show a top-level `QWidget`, drag it to a new position on the desktop, then call `widget->hide()` followed by `widget::show()`, it generally reappears in a different place from where it was previously.

I can add code to the subclass which saves and restores its geometry, but I'm wondering if there's an in-Qt system for giving hints to the window manager as to where the widget should appear when shown.

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I create a "Qt Widgets Application" and drag in a QPushButton, then add the following code:

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    hide();
    show();
}
```

Run the program, drag the widget to a new position, and then click on the button and I find that the widget is still in the same place, not like you said

Comment: That's because your window manager has a different policy. My question is, can Qt influence that policy?